# CoreData and sqlite3 - existing data disappears on simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data

I'm testing a sqlite3 database in iphone accessed by core data.

I created the file db.sqlite3 and created a table mccategory in there with some records in it and dragged it into the resources folder in my project.

```
CREATE TABLE category (  id ,  category,  parent_category,  short_name,  long_name,  description);
```

I built the core data model entity mccategory in proj.xcdatamodeld

I saw that when running the application it was retrieving 0 rows, so i opened the db.sqlite3 file from the command line and saw that the original category table was not present and a new one created zmccategory with some additional fields.

```
CREATE TABLE ZMCCATEGORY ( 
Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
Z_ENT INTEGER, 
Z_OPT INTEGER, 
ZCATEGORY VARCHAR, 
ZDESC VARCHAR, 
ZID VARCHAR, 
ZLONG_NAME VARCHAR, 
ZPARENT_CATEGORY VARCHAR, 
ZSHORT_NAME VARCHAR );
```

I realised that the original table I created had been lost and a new one created based on the definition of the entity I created in the proj.xcdatamodeld file.

So I copied the newly generated zmccategory table and inserted some rows into it and dragged the new file into xcode again.

```
INSERT INTO ZMCCATEGORY (Z_PK,Z_ENT,Z_OPT,ZCATEGORY,ZDESC,ZID,ZLONG_NAME,     ZPARENT_CATEGORY,ZSHORT_NAME) 
VALUES (1,1,1,'All Categories','All Categories','1','All Categories','0','All Categories');
```

I re-ran the simulator and it still showed 0 rows returned. so I again opened the db.sqlite3 file at the command line and saw again there were no rows in the table.

Is there any solution that allows a previously, correctly populated sqlite3 database and table to be imported into xcode 5. This is turning out harder than it needs to be.

Comment: have you copied the entire file created by CoreData, or simply created the table in your own file? (why will you ever want to interact with CoreData in this fashion?)

Comment: i copied the entire file created by core data. It seemed a normal thing to me to create a database externally and import it into iphone for use with coredata. Am I missing something in how this should be used? In the mean time I'm going to load the sqlite3 database using a coredata method.